# Replace Text with Image by get user input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to modify this program to replace image with text. In this program, the value of input box should reflect in the place of balloon image. Could you help me ?

Program link:

```
$('#draw').click(function() {
    var text = document.getElementById('txtBallon').value;

        var $ballon = $('#ballon'),
            $canvas = $('#canvas');
        var ballon_x = $ballon.offset().left - $canvas.offset().left,
            ballon_y = $ballon.offset().top - $canvas.offset().top;

        context.drawImage(ballon, ballon_x, ballon_y);

        $ballon.hide();
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vengreat/V92Gn/3881/)

Comment: What actually want. You want to replace text written textinput in place of balloon when draw click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like following way:

```
context.font = "30px Verdana";
context.fillText(text,ballon_x,ballon_y);
```

Instead of `context.drawImage(ballon, ballon_x, ballon_y);`

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/3882/)**

**[Updated Fiddle with text drag](http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/3885/)**

Comment: thanks a lot. please could you make that text draggable ?

Comment: draggable after draw?

Comment: no before draw, to do that text should reflect simultaneously when i type in input box, then drag it and draw.

Comment: @VenkadeshS Check this. http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/3884/. type in text. beside that label you can drag anywhere and click on draw. You can make changes as per your requirement.

Comment: yeah. draw is not working. but this is for your reference to complete it: https://jsfiddle.net/vengreat/7r2007nn/2/

Comment: thank you ketan, its working now, why draw button is moving if i type more texts ?

Comment: @VenkadeshS It's because when you type label width increase. http://jsfiddle.net/V92Gn/3886/

Comment: for that, can i set initial text place(Top or Bottom) on image in javascript ?

Comment: if you can, do it for me else no problem i will do it thanks for your help.

Comment: appreciable work. thanks ketan, May I know how did you set initial position of text ?. Next time it will help me.

Comment: @VenkadeshS you can check in css. `#dragText` there is `top` and `left` set and `position:absolute;` given

Comment: Its is working only in jsfiddle, not working in local machine. could you please provide it as zip file to download it.

Comment: Have you include http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js and  http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js ?

Comment: No I didnt add it in my file. is that fine ? else please give link to download your program.

Comment: You can download from http://plnkr.co/edit/jBim5cdIwnCDNQAHLuAk?p=preview. Right top there is option to download

Comment: Thanks ketan. Now its working. Finally last question how to download it as png after draw ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d');
  var background = document.getElementById('background');
  context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);

  $('.drag').draggable();

  $('#draw').click(function() {
      var $canvas = $('#canvas');

var textX = $('#myText').offset().left - $canvas.offset().left;
var textY = $('#myText').offset().top - $canvas.offset().top + 12;
        context.font= "13px Arial";
        context.fillText($("#myText").text(),textX,textY);

        $('#myText').hide();
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});

$("#theText").keyup(function(){
    $("#myText").text($(this).val());
});
```

[Here is the updated **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1r4a0yae/)

Comment: Hi., you are merely come to answer. But My expectation is  "text should reflect simultaneously when i type in input box, then drag it and draw finally".

Comment: @VenkadeshS You mean you should be able to type the text, then drag it, then click draw to fix it on the canvas? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: yes of course. this is for your reference to reflect text then finally i have to draw it. https://jsfiddle.net/vengreat/7r2007nn/2/

Comment: Else it would be helpful if you add draw functionality in this  sample program.https://jsfiddle.net/vengreat/7r2007nn/2/

Comment: In the answer I provided, u can type in the textbox, then drag it to where you require, then click draw to fix it. What specifically needs to be changed?

Comment: you also right with functionally. But i need only text on image not a text box shown there. that is need to be fixed.

Comment: I updated my answer. The checkbox is at the bottom :)

Comment: Interesting. This is what I expected and how do you set initial text position (Top ) text on image ?

Comment: The initial position is defined by the CSS class `.drag` :)

Comment: hi ahs N., Its is working only in jsfiddle, not working in local machine. could you please store zip file to download it.

Comment: @VenkadeshS Ensure that you JS codes are *after* the `body` tag and also that you have included the JQuery library.

Comment: I have added now still not working in local. http://plnkr.co/edit/5Dco1cE0WuL3nHZ7NRSA?p=preview.:(

Comment: [Here it is...](http://plnkr.co/edit/ETCNtfJMaHCPwjffSS24?p=preview)...just moved the JS to the bottom as I suggested before

Comment: thanks. could you help me to download it as png after i drawn ?